# increasing speed of python loop for ML algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, image-processing, machine-learning

I am trying to perform maximum likelihood algorithm on an image where mean vectors, and covariance matrices are known. The problem is that the calculation is really really slow...and I work on quite big images (5100X7020).

The following piece of code shows the calculation of the probability map of a given class for pixels in the image

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import inv
from numpy.linalg import det
...

probImage1 = []
probImage1Vector = []

norm = 1.0 / (np.power((2*np.pi), i/2) * np.sqrt(np.linalg.det(covMatrixClass1)))
for x in xrange(x_img):
    for y in xrange(y_img):
        X = realImage[x,y]
        mult1 = np.multiply(-0.5,np.transpose(X - meanVectorClass1))
        mult2 = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(covMatrixClass1),(X - meanVectorClass1))
        multMult = np.dot(mult1,mult2)
        expo = np.exp(multMult)     
        probImage1Vector.append(np.multiply(norm,expo))
    probImage1.append(probImage1Vector)
    probImage1Vector = []
```

Do you have any idea how to speed up this algorithm?

Thanks in advance

**Update:**

I decreased time calculation time by placing the matrix inverse calculation outside the for loop, but still it is still very slow...
Itself iterating over the image and getting the pixel value doesnt take too much time, but even a simple matrix subtraction slow it down significantly...

i,j = covMatrixClass1.shape

probImage1 = []
probImage1Vector = []

```
norm = 1.0 / (np.power((2*np.pi), i/2) *      np.sqrt(np.linalg.det(covMatrixClass1)))
covMatrixInverz = np.linalg.inv(covMatrixClass1)
for x in xrange(x_img):
    for y in xrange(y_img):
        X = realImage[x,y]
        pixelValueDifference = X - meanVectorClass1
        mult1 = np.multiply(-0.5,np.transpose(pixelValueDifference))
        mult2 = np.dot(covMatrixInverz,pixelValueDifference)
        multMult = np.dot(mult1,mult2)
        expo = np.exp(multMult)     
        probImage1Vector.append(np.multiply(norm,expo))
    probImage1.append(probImage1Vector)
    probImage1Vector = []
```

PLEASE, any advice how to speed up this code is appriciated!

Comment: Well, if you have to do multiple dot products and matrix inversions for 36 million pixels, it's going to take a while. Can you operate on fewer pixels? Can you pre-calculate some of those matrix operations or perhaps cache some of the values and interpolate? I guess the real question is whether you're okay with an *approximation* rather than the exact value for each pixel.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the hints. Indeed, placing e.g. the inv(matrix) calculation over the for loop, and calculating only once the vector subtraction helpd to decrease the calculation time. Itself iteration over the image, and getting the pixel values does not take to much time, but if some simple math is also taking place like vector subtraction, the it increasing significantly. Why is it so? Could you please explain a lit bit how do you mean "approximation rather than the exact value for each pixel"?